# Efficiency with XSLT function calls

Tags: xslt

Is storing the result of a function call more efficient than calling the function multiple times?

Example -

```
<xsl:variable name="time" select="current-dateTime()"/>
<myTime><xsl:value-of select="$time"/></myTime>
<yourTime><xsl:value-of select="$time"/></yourTime>
```

than

```
<myTime><xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/></myTime>
<yourTime><xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/></yourTime>
```

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, such things depend a lot on the actual implementation. The one thing I'd look out for is whether the function call may change its value between two calls - that may be important.

In the case here the function is stable (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#stable)), therefore implementations probably have a cached value for that anyways, so that calling the function is basically just a very cheap "getter" implementation (most likely about the same cost as reading a variable).

Comment: I gave a bad example because the time could have changed. But what about current-group() where the group is expected to be the same?

Comment: My answer is just as valid - that depends on the implementation. If the XSLT is compiled it may "see" the two calls and if it can determine that they would return the same result it may optimize that itself just like using a variable.

Comment: Putting your examples into a `<xsl:for-each select="1 to 10000">` and timing them, the first took an average of 5207 ms and the second 5047 ms. So, about equal. If you do need to micro-optimize, oXygen has a very nice profiler that shows a breakdown of time spent and where your "hotspots" are.

Comment: Thanks Mads. It seems that the first one took longer. Could this be because you kept the variable initialization in the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Well, (a) it obviously depends on the function, and (b) it obviously depends on the XSLT processor. The only way of getting an answer to this kind of performance question is to measure it. And even measurement may not help, because to make measurements you typically have to do artificial things like calling a function 10000 times, and when you do that, the optimizer might treat your code differently from if you only call it once.